# Trigger S3 Object without upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a feeling the answer to my question will be a correct google term that i am missing but here we go.

I need to trigger all objects in an `s3` bucket without uploading. The reason being i have a lambda that gets triggered on `PutObject` and i want to reprocess all those files again. There are huge images and re-uploading does not sound like a good idea.

I am trying to do this in `nodejs` but any language that anyone is comfortable with will help and  i will translate.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need to trigger all objects in an s3 bucket"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 Event can trigger an AWS Lambda function when an object is created/deleted/replicated.

However, it is not possible to "trigger the object" -- the object would need to be created/deleted/replicated to cause the Amazon S3 Event to be generated.

As an alternative, you could create a small program that lists the objects in the bucket, and then **directly invokes** the AWS Lambda function, passing the object details in the `event` message to make it look like it came from Amazon S3. There is a sample S3 Event in the Lambda 'test' function -- you could copy this template and have your program insert the appropriate bucket and object key. Your Lambda function would then process it exactly as if an S3 Event had triggered the function.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what explained above, you can use [AWS S3 Batch Operations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/).
We used this to encrypt existing objects in the S3 bucket which were not encrypted earlier.

This was the easiest out of the box solution available in the S3 console itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also loop through all objects in the bucket and add a tag.  Next, adjust your trigger event to include tag changes. Code sample in bash to follow after I test it.